# Colorblindness in females and random X chromosome inactivation

Tags: human-biology, genetics, vision

From [Annenberg Learner](https://www.learner.org/courses/biology/textbook/gender/gender_5.html):

> Because the X is inactivated randomly in cells, **one cell could have the maternal X inactivated, while the adjacent cell could have the paternal
>   X inactivated**. This causes a pattern of gene expression called mosaicism, which occurs when different alleles of X-linked genes are expressed in different cells.

However, this seems at odds with colorblindness being more likely in males.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness):

> The genes that produce photopigments are carried on the X chromosome; if some of these genes are missing or damaged, **color blindness will be expressed in males with a higher probability than in females because males only have one X chromosome, whereas females have two** and a functional gene on only one of the X chromosomes is sufficient to yield the necessary photopigments.

*Question*: If X chromosomes are randomly inactivated cell by cell, shouldn't the fully functional photopigment-producing gene be inactivated approximately half the time?  In which case, wouldn't we instead see females with colorblindness with higher frequency as males, but experiencing colorblindness to a lesser extent?  (After all, two X chromosomes means two chances for a dysfunctional gene.)

I'm guessing I'm missing a piece of the puzzle here, e.g., perhaps the relevant cells "know" to inactivate the dysfunctional X chromosome, or perhaps it's to do with X chromosomes only being incompletely inactivated.

Comment: @Christiaan. I was thinking the exact same thing about the tags. But it had a part about sex determination in it, and while not what I would consider sex determination it was related to sex-linkage... I agree with your decision.

Comment: @AMR - I just posted in chat. Will ping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In heterozygote females with colour defect genes on the X-chromosome, even if approximately half of their photoreceptors are dysfunctional they usually have enough functional cone photoreceptors to have normal colour vision.

From [Molecular genetics of colour vision deficiencies](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1444-0938.2004.tb05052.x/abstract;jsessionid=3A56A7B5A492E8A1C27217B228117C37.f03t02):

> Due to X-chromosome inactivation during early development,
>   heterozygotes are mosaics for two populations of cones, one expressing
>   visual pigment genes encoded by an X-chromosome that would cause
>   colour vision defects in males, and the other expressing genes that
>   would confer normal colour vision on a male. In support of this,
>   patches of defective colour perception were detected by shining a very
>   narrow beam of red or green light into the retinas of female
>   heterozygotes for X-linked colour vision defects. The majority of
>   heterozygote women (carriers of colour vision defects) have normal
>   colour vision.

This means that  – in most cases – for a female to be colourblind, her father must be colourblind and her mother must be either a heterozygote (carrier) or homozygote colourblind. In a male, only the mother's X-chromosome determines whether he inherits the defective genes, so he is more likely to have the colourblind trait.